# tinymce was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

I have a problem with a librabry I am using. It tells me tinmce is used before it was defined. This librabry makes from text area a wysiwyg editor. but right now it's not working correctly.

Hope anyone can help me out with this!
Thanks!

```js
tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});
```

```html
<?php include "../includes/db.php"; ?>
<?php include "functions.php"; ?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_role'])){
        
        if($_SESSION['user_role'] !== 'admin'){
            
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        
        } 
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Welcome To Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    
    <!-- Google chart librabry voor google charts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    
    <!-- tinymce wysiwyg editor voor posts -->
    <script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    

</head>

<body>
```

Comment: I have made a file called scripts.js to put the: tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});

Comment: Are you using Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Apache:

> Problem is caused by default Apache option EnableSendfile. You must turn it OFF by removing the # character in the httpd.conf file.

see: [TinyMCE-Installation: Windows specific Apache configuration](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:Installation)

from:

```
#EnableSendfile off
```

to:

```
EnableSendfile off
```

Comment: I should replace all #??

Comment: @KevinVugts no just EnableSendfile
from: **#EnableSendfile off** to: **EnableSendfile off** (remove the  # for this line)

Comment: I did this: #
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off

Comment: Actually it is working. But the bold function for wysiwyg is not working.

Comment: @KevinVugts So the (EnableSendfile off) worked?
Could [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1049640) be the new issue?